# checking if a number is even but not zero, in 1 condition?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I don't think it is possible but can this be done in 1 condition instead of 2?

I'm trying not to do this

```
bool test = (Number1 & 1) == 0 && (Number1 > 0);
```

or this

```
bool test = (Number1 & 1) == 0 && (Number1 != 0);
```

Comment: @Blachshma, there is a difference between the bit is not and AND number is not zero, if Number1 is 6, bit1 is not set but it is greater than 0.

Comment: What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: @Jon, short version is, getting Number1 is expensive and I cannot store it in a local variable.

Comment: @Stas, I updated my question to answer your question

Comment: Why can you not store it in a local variable?

Comment: What result should negative numbers give?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will return true for all even numbers >= 2 and false for all odd numbers, as well as all numbers <= 0:

```
bool test = ((Number1 - 1) % 2 == 1);
```

Comment: hmm thanks this gave me this idea; `((Number1-1) & (1 << 31 | 1)) == 1` for in32 and `((Number1-1) & (1 << 63 | 1)) == 1` for int64 which in the end is faster than modulo, so far my test is working

Comment: Out of personal unfamiliarity, I tend to steer away from recommending bitwise operations, but yes, what you have looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is technically putting `Number1` into a variable, I think it'll work. I'm assuming `Number1` is returned from a long running function call or property? Either way:

```
private bool IsEvenNotZero(int num) {
    return (num & 1) == 0 && (num != 0);
}

bool test = IsEvenNotZero(Number1);
```

This will put it in a parameter and you can test the parameter twice that way. I don't know why you can't put `Number1` in a normal variable, and without knowing more about the situation I don't know if any better can be done.